# Facing Problems in Converting to Functional Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, react-hooks, web-audio-api

This is a very small two-page project, so this won't take much time.

I am trying to convert [this](https://github.com/matt-eric/web-audio-fft-visualization-with-react-hooks) Github repo from class-based component to functional component. I am very close but the logic is just not working properly.
The useState hook especially, as in the values are not getting saved. So I tried a different approach.

This is the expected output which is the live demo of the original project:

https://matt-eric.github.io/web-audio-fft-visualization-with-react-hooks/

And this is where I am. [This is the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-shannon-8myi1?file=/src/components/functionCont.jsx).

Ignore the `The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.` error for now. Click on the `x` and refresh the small `project window` (not your browser tab) a couple of times until the audio plays on refresh. This is because google stops you from playing music on load.

I want to audio to play with the click of the button and not on load. But it is not working.

Thank whoever goes and looks into it.

Comment: It would be better to provide the code here in the question, rather than having an external link that viewers have to click to follow. This will help people looking at your question to see if it matches the same problem they are facing. If you don't mind providing your React Class component here in the question that you want to convert to a functional component with React hooks, I would be happy to help! At my job, I have converted many React Class components into functional hook components as our team pushes to use latest and greatest technology stacks.

Comment: @JasonBellomy Sorry for the inconvenience. I provided external links because it was very confusing for me to understand. I wanted this to be as effortless as possible for anyone that was going to look at the code as well as able to run it in real-time. I wanted the people to interact with the program and get the problem fixed. Otherwise, I wouldn't have spent extra time setting up the sandbox. But I'll keep this in mind next time. You are great.

Answer (score 3):

There's some cleanup needed but this is working. https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-wildflower-c5b35

All I really did was put all the functions in a `useCallback` made `audioFile` a ref, and then made the `toggleAudio` function which either plays or pauses the audio depending on its current state. One of the biggest problems I saw was that you were trying to initialize the audio on click, but that really should be done on mount, then the audio just starts when you click. Also if you initialize on every click then it causes errors because it's already initialized.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I was literally doing the same thing. LOL. You beat me to it :)

Comment: Also, he doesn't need to use a ref, he just needs to memoize the value (since he wants to intialize it once and never have it change). useMemo is made just for this use case in which you can save the value in state just once on initial load and it will never change (it will be cached).

Comment: Yeah I like your use of `useMemo`. I've never really thought to use it like that, but it makes total sense.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also had an idea of what the problem was but had no idea how to implement it. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Using your sandbox, I found a couple of things missing:

1. You needed to memoize your audoFile (since you create a new audio and it never changes)
2. Your functions need to be stable, and therefore need to be react hook functions, specifically useCallback functions.
3. In your onClick function in the demo (the start button) you called to initalizeAudioAnalyzer but that was already intialized with your useEffect on functionCont.jsx and doesn't need to be initialized again. Once I removed this, it all worked.

Here is the fixed up code that is now playing the audio:

functionCont.jsx:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import VisualDemo from "./functionViz";
// import VisualDemo from "./VisualDemo";
import soundFile from "../audio/water.mp3";

const FunctionCont = () => {
  const audioFile = useMemo(() => {
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    return audio;
  } , []);

  const [audioData, setAudioData] = useState();
  let frequencyBandArray = [...Array(25).keys()];

  const initializeAudioAnalyser = useCallback(() => {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioFile);
    const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    audioFile.src = soundFile;
    
    analyser.fftSize = 64;

    source.connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.connect(analyser);

    setAudioData(analyser);
    audioFile.play();
  }, [audioFile]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeAudioAnalyser();
  }, [initializeAudioAnalyser]);

  const getFrequencyData = useCallback((styleAdjuster) => {
    const bufferLength = audioData.frequencyBinCount;
    const amplitudeArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    audioData.getByteFrequencyData(amplitudeArray);
    styleAdjuster(amplitudeArray);
  }, [audioData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <VisualDemo
        frequencyBandArray={frequencyBandArray}
        getFrequencyData={getFrequencyData}
        // audioData={audioData}
        audioFile={audioFile}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FunctionCont;
```

functionViz.jsx

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import EqualizerIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Equalizer";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import "../stylesheets/App.scss";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  flexContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: "25%"
  }
}));

const VisualDemo = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const amplitudeValues = useRef(null);

  function adjustFreqBandStyle(newAmplitudeData) {
    amplitudeValues.current = newAmplitudeData;
    let domElements = props.frequencyBandArray.map((num) =>
      document.getElementById(num)
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < props.frequencyBandArray.length; i++) {
      let num = props.frequencyBandArray[i];
      domElements[
        num
      ].style.backgroundColor = `rgb(0, 255, ${amplitudeValues.current[num]})`;
      domElements[num].style.height = `${amplitudeValues.current[num]}px`;
    }
  }

  function runSpectrum() {
    props.getFrequencyData(adjustFreqBandStyle);
    requestAnimationFrame(runSpectrum);
  }

  function handleStartButtonClick() {
    requestAnimationFrame(runSpectrum);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Tooltip title="Start" aria-label="Start" placement="right">
          <IconButton
            id="startButton"
            onClick={handleStartButtonClick}
            // disabled={!!props.audioData ? true : false}
          >
            <EqualizerIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>

      <div className={classes.flexContainer}>
        {props.frequencyBandArray.map((num) => (
          <Paper
            className={"frequencyBands"}
            elevation={4}
            id={num}
            key={num}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default VisualDemo;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I did the (3) one just so it doesn't crash. I had no idea about the useCallback hook or its uses before. I'll look into it and learn. Thank you so much again.